# Why HashMap does not guarantee that the order of the map will remain constant over time

Tags: java, hashmap

I was reading about difference between Hashmap and Hashtable here:
http://javarevisited.blogspot.sg/2010/10/difference-between-hashmap-and.html

Can anyone throw some light on why it says following?

*"5. HashMap does not guarantee that the order of the map will remain constant over time."*

Could the order change during re-hashing, that is why?

It would be also nice if you could point me to resource or list of collections who exhibit such behavior of not guaranteeing order to be remain constant.

AFIK, ArrayList gives such gurantee (let me know if I am wrong)

EDIT: 'Order of map' = maybe order in which keys or values are entered.

Comment: Use LinkedHashMap if you'd like to preserve insert order of keys

Comment: I'm not sure the article is correct on this difference. I don't see any guarantee in the javadoc that `Hashtable` will preserve order, it just doesn't explicitly mention that it doesn't (whereas the javadoc for `HashMap` is explicit).

Comment: Can you define "order of a map"? IMHO, it is a bit wrong to say it is not preserved when such a thing does not even exist in the first place.

Comment: @Ingo: All maps (and sets) have an implicit order as defined by their iterators. In the case of a `Map`, it is the `entrySet().iterator()`, that defines its order

Comment: @LukasEder The iterator will indeed return the elements in some order - but that doesn't mean that the thing it gets the elements from defines (or has) any order. Consider an Iterator<Double> where next() is Random.nextDouble().

Comment: @Ingo: Thus *implicit* order

Comment: @LukasEder - I find it conceptually easier to say "no order", in cases where even the unpredictable implicit order, as you call it, can change.

Comment: @Ingo: As the OP cited, *there is no guarantee for constant order*. On the other hand, the [`java.util.Map`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) javadoc clearly reads: *The order of a map is defined as the order in which the iterators on the map's collection views return their elements.*

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A [HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) has no order - at any time. It is actually not used for that purpose. The order *may* change even when not rehashing.

If you need the order to remain constant, use a  [LinkedHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html)

Comment: Try adding 0 to 10 to a HashSet, it will be in sorted order. :0

Comment: Any proof for that claim, @PeterLawrey, or just empirical "evidence"?

Comment: He is right but that's only true because of the implementation. Nothing guarantees that it is always true.

Comment: Thanks for information. I will wait for some more useful comments/answer before accepting this as an answer.

Comment: @Ingo, the proof is in the code.  Integer's hashCode just returns the value which results in each number being in buckets 0 to 10, but as Vakimshaar points out there is no guarantee of this.

Comment: This is not any answer to the question. The question is why does it have no order? What's in the implementation that makes the order change?

Answer (score 6):

The point of a hashing strategy is to place objects in a pseudo random manner.  It does this so that most of the time, only one key/element will be hashed to a given bucket. This allows an O(1) lookup time.  When a HashMap or Hashtable grows, the number of buckets changes and the keys/elements are placed in another pseudo random manner.

The simplest solution to this is to use LinkedHashMap.  This will keep order of addition or optionally order of last access. I prefer to use this collection because it makes debugging easier as I can predict where an object is likely to be and sometimes the order an object was added can be useful information.

BTW If you are interested in how many orders a small number of keys can have [Order of elements in a hash collection](http://vanillajava.blogspot.co.uk/2011/09/order-of-elements-in-hash-collection.html)

Answer (score 5):

For me the following code:

```
Map <Integer, Object> map = new HashMap <Integer, Object> (4);

map.put (60, null);
map.put (48, null);
map.put (29, null);

System.out.println (map);

map.put (47, null);
map.put (15, null);
map.put (53, null);

map.remove (47);
map.remove (15);
map.remove (53);

System.out.println (map);
```

outputs:

```
{29=null, 48=null, 60=null}
{48=null, 29=null, 60=null}
```

The order changed because of the re-hashing that happens when the initial capacity (here, 4) is exceeded. Even though the additional entries are removed again, the original order isn't restored.

Comment: Hmm, that's not really an answer. It's just a rather arbitrary example of *what* happens when using `HashMap`, not *why* it happens

Comment: Stepping this example in debugger will show you why.  Map capacity was 4, rehash happened when another three elements were added and order of first three elements was changed.  When latest three elements were removed, original order was not restored.

Comment: Hehe :-) I see. Note that a good answer on Stack Overflow includes such comments directly in the answer. If you'll add your explanation to your answer about *why* this happens (e.g. inline comments, some text, etc), I'll upvote.

Comment: Thank you! This is the best answer I found so far. The example provided makes it super clear and easy to try it out locally.

Answer (score 1):

A HashMap has number of buckets (implemented as an array) in which to store entries.

When an item is added to the map, it is assigned to a buckets based on a value derived of its hashCode and the bucket size of the HashMap. (Note that it's possible that the bucket is already occupied, which is called a collision. That's handled gracefully and correctly, but I'll ignore that handling for the description because it doesn't change the concept).

[Why HashMap does not guarantee that the order of the map will remain constant over time](http://mkbansal.wordpress.com/2010/06/24/hashmap-how-it-works/)