# Cause of the difference in the insertion order of HashMap and LinkedHashMap

Tags: java, hashmap

I understand that the items of a HashMap do not maintain or are not arranged in a constant order, although sometimes it does, so here's my question: What condition would make the HashMap print its output in that ordered form or is it an arbitrary process?

Comment: Good old fashioned dumb luck (and there is no such thing as "the output of a `HashMap`")

Comment: Just use an implementation of [`SortedMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html), a [`TreeMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) should be sufficient…

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why HashMap does not guarantee that the order of the map will remain constant over time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14687406/why-hashmap-does-not-guarantee-that-the-order-of-the-map-will-remain-constant-ov)

Comment: "although sometimes it does" -- There's no *although*. The ordering of HashMap entries is completely arbitrary. Don't try to predict the behavior of things which are purposefully left unspecified.

Comment: _in that ordered form_ What is _that_ referring to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What condition would make the HashMap print its output in [order of insertion]?

The iteration order of the standard library's `HashMap` is deterministic, but it varies in ways that are difficult to predict.  Factors affecting that order include the map's initial capacity and load factor, the hash codes (and to a lesser extent, the values) of the keys inserted into it and removed from it, and the order of insertions and removals.

For a given set of reasonable map parameters and a flexible-enough key type, it should be possible to compute key insertion / deletion sequences that result in insertion-order iteration of the final map contents, but only by sheer luck could you expect to see insertion-order iteration of a `HashMap` populated with real-world data.

For example, without testing or consulting the implementation, I speculate that if you use `Integer` keys (whose hash codes are their `int` values), chosen such that each ends up in a separate hash bucket and inserted in ascending order, then you might see them iterated in insertion order.  This is not intended to be a recipe, just a mechanism to convey the kind of considerations that would be involved.

Overall, do not choose `HashMap` if you care about iteration order.  No good can come from that.